# Does OS X/Xcode have a default info pop-up?

Tags: macos, popup

I'm looking to do a pop-up similar to this one. Would I have to create the images myself or is there something I'm missing? [image: popup]

Edit: A mod must have edited my post without reading or viewing the screenshot. I want to do this in OS X, not iOS

Comment: Here you can find many "well" created pop up views/controllers for your app, look for your match here, https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=popup

Answer (score 0):

iPhone don't have such info pop ups but it's in iPad development. For iPhone you can create custom pop. see here also: [Best Method to Show a Popup Transparent Window on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509392/best-method-to-show-a-popup-transparent-window-on-iphone)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I'm looking to do this in OS X!