# Expandable List View In Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

i am tying to implement expandable list view as a popup view using Xamarin IOS.
Please find the below image.

[image]

Can any one give brief description to implement the above requirement.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom popup which has a tableview in it with expendable rows.

To create a custom popup you can something like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19509582/5852062

When thats done, you should make the custom view use a tableview and make some rows expendable, something like this:

http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

Note that this is in swift/objective-c but perfectly translatable to c#.